# WebLogic 10.3.2 Performance issues

Tags: java, weblogic, weblogic-10.x

If I deploy to my local machine the application runs 4 times faster then when it is deployed to our Sun Application Server.  Im not getting any memory errors and it does not mater how many sessions i have going.  It just seems like every request waits before it runs.  If I plug my machine into the same port as the server it still runs faster so im guessing its a Weblogic setting

My start up specifics

```
weblogic.Server
Virtual Machine: 
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM version 14.3-b01
Vendor: 
Sun Microsystems Inc.
Name: 
Uptime: 
15 days 21 hours 18 minutes
Process CPU time: 
16 days 16 hours 19 minutes
JIT compiler: 
HotSpot 64-Bit Server Compiler
Total compile time: 
12 minutes

Live threads: 
    69
Peak: 
    71
Daemon threads: 
    68
Total threads started: 
51,573
Current classes loaded: 
27,654
Total classes loaded: 
33,709
Total classes unloaded: 
 6,055



Current heap size: 
1,324,827 kbytes
Maximum heap size: 
1,867,776 kbytes
Committed memory: 
1,730,240 kbytes
Pending finalization: 
0 objects
Garbage collector: 
Name = 'PS MarkSweep', Collections = 153, Total time spent = 37 minutes
Garbage collector: 
Name = 'PS Scavenge', Collections = 21,402, Total time spent = 40 minutes

Operating System: 
SunOS 5.10
Architecture: 
sparcv9
Number of processors: 
48
Committed virtual memory: 
3,013,032 kbytes
Total physical memory: 
66,879,488 kbytes
Free physical memory: 
21,949,936 kbytes
Total swap space: 
20,932,024 kbytes
Free swap space: 
20,932,024 kbytes

VM arguments: 
-Dweblogic.nodemanager.ServiceEnabled=true 
-Dweblogic.security.SSL.ignoreHostnameVerification=false 
-Dweblogic.ReverseDNSAllowed=false 
-Xms1024m -Xmx2048m 
-XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing a memory analysis. One way is to take a heap dump during a transaction and perform an analysis it.

This is the best way to go about it, use a tool like [JRockit mission control](http://www.oracle.com/missioncontrol) or [Oracle VisualVM](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/) to perform analysis. This will let you see what happens in your JVM real time. You could take your application off the JVM, connect to it and load your application and see information like heap and gc. They have many more features and definitely something a developer must have.

EDIT:
I have updated the link for mission control. Thanks Klara!

Comment: Newer link for Mission Control - oracle.com/missioncontrol

Comment: That I was not aware of. I think they are trying to phase it out and aren't doing a fabulous enough job :D

Comment: No phasing out that I'm aware of (since I'm on the team..)

Comment: You are an Oracle person?

Comment: Yes. In the Java group (Java Mission Control dev team)